# Which Attribute Of The Queues is Referenced In Diverts?

Tags: jboss, jms

The examples of diverts have the same name for the queue as the entry so I am not clear which I use for the divert reference. e.g.

```
<jms-destinations>
    <jms-queue name="VendorQueue">
        <entry name="queue/vendor"/>
        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/queue/vendor"/>
        <durable>false</durable>
    </jms-queue>    
</jms-destinations>
```

Is this correct?

```
jms-queue add --queue-address=monitoring --entries=queue/monitoring
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default/divert=my-divert:add(divert-address=jms.queue.VendorQueue,forwarding-address=jms.queue.monitoring,exclusive=false)
```

i.e. is the divert-address supposed to be `jms.queue.VendorQueue` or `jms.queue.vendor`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the correct divert-address you need to run this

```
/subsystem=messaging/hornetq-server=default:read-children-names(child-type="jms-queue")
```

Then prefix jms.queue
e.g.

```
{
 "outcome" => "success",
 "result" => [
 "VendorQueue",
 "monitoring"
 ]
}
```

becomes

```
jms.queue.VendorQueue
```

In reference to the xml, the jms-queue name is the attribute you reference not the entry name.